# How To Install GraphViz For PHP On Ubunutu

Tags: php

What I want to do is install GraphViz for PHP on Ubuntu.

I tried `pear install Image_GraphViz`, it installed but does not work for me.

Then I tried downloading the file from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_ubuntu.php).

File name : `libgv-php5_2.32.0-1~raring_amd64.deb` When I run the file it says dependency is not satisfiable libgraphviz4.

All I want to do is run the code below which is from their documentation. Unfortunately I can not find `GraphViz.php` to download.

```
<?php
require_once 'GraphViz.php';

$gv = new Image_GraphViz();
$gv->addEdge(array('wake up'        => 'visit bathroom'));
$gv->addEdge(array('visit bathroom' => 'make coffee'));
$gv->image();
?>
```

How can I fix this issue? Where can I download `GraphViz.php`

Comment: This should probably be on Server Fault

Comment: No, this does not belong on Server Fault.  Server Fault is for *professional sysadmin* questions.  Getting PEAR modules working is way, way out of scope for SF, and is perfectly on topic on SO.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, so?  It's still on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the [`libgv-php5` [image: Install libgv-php5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libgv-php5) package:

> **PHP5 bindings for graphviz**
>
> Graphviz is a set of graph drawing tools. See the description of the graphviz
>    package for a full description.
>
> This package contains the PHP5 bindings.

Using your favourite package management, e.g. `apt-get`, do:

```
sudo apt-get install libgv-php5
```

This should install the Graphviz for PHP in the paths used by the Ubuntu packaged version of PHP (automatically enabled in the `php.ini` `.d` directory).

You will then have to change your `require_once` statement to match the Ubuntu packaged version. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/gv.3php.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
include('libgv-php5/gv.php');
...
?>
```

Also don't forget to restart your webserver if you're running PHP as a module.

Comment: Still I get 
Fatal error: Class 'Image_GraphViz' not found in /var/www/

Comment: @Dasun How about replacing your `require_once` with `require_once 'libgv-php5/gv.php';` ?

Answer (score 3):

You should install the `graphviz` package via apt:

```
$ sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Then [Image_Graphviz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Graphviz) is able to use the `dot` command that is provided by `graphviz`.

Comment: Where can I find the GraphViz.php file to be included?

Comment: @Dasun if you correctly ran the `pear` command, then the file will be in your include path already.

Comment: Still I get 
Fatal error: Class 'Image_GraphViz' not found in /var/www/

Comment: Follow the PEAR setup instructions: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Answer (score 0):

GraphViz.php is the file contained in the Image_GraphViz package. It would likely be in a folder named Image_GraphViz. Therefore include the full path in your require_once statement.
The file defines the Image_GraphViz class that provides an interface to the actual GraphViz system (installed separately).

Answer (score 0):

At first reinstall pear:

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar    
php go-pear.phar
```

After that install graphviz via pear:

```
sudo pear install Image_GraphViz
```

That's all.